# How should I write this PHP array into a Python list?

Tags: php, python, arrays, list

I am new to Python, so I need a little guidence. I have a php file that I am porting over into python and can't seem to find a good way to convert the following php array into a python array or list. I did some research and found that python list are better.

PHP array (names from sql query)

```
$heads = array(
'ServerHostID' => 'ServerHostID',
'SERVER_NAME' => 'Server Name',
'SERVER_NUMBER' => 'Server Number',
'SERVER_OPERATIONAL_STATUS' => 'Server Operational Status',
'HOST_NAME' => 'Host Name',
'HOST_NUMBER' => 'Host Number',
'ALIAS' => 'Alias',
'UTILIZATION_PERCENTAGE' => 'Utilization Percentage',
'DATA_SIZE' => 'Data Size',
'HAS_REMOTE_ACCESS' => 'Has Remote Access',
'CLUSTER' => 'Cluster',
'VM_NAME' => 'VM Name',
'VM_IP_ADDRESS' => 'VM IP Address',
'CPU_ALLOCATED' => 'CPU Allocated',
'MEMORY_ALLOCATED' => 'Memory Allocated',
'IS_VIRTUAL' => 'Is Virtual',
'LOGICAL_PARTITION' => 'Logical Partition',
'PHYSICAL_PARTITION' => 'Physical Partition',
'OPERATING_SYSTEM_SOFTWARE' => 'Operating System Software',
'OPERATIONAL_USE' => 'Operational Use',
'FUNCTIONAL_USE' => 'Functional Use',
'HOST_OPERATIONAL_STATUS' => 'Host Operational Status'
);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Err, no. You want a `dict`.

```
heads = {
  'ServerHostID': 'ServerHostID',
  'SERVER_NAME': 'Server Name',
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in python.

```
>>> heads = {'ServerHostID' : 'ServerHostID','SERVER_NAME' : 'Server Name'}
>>> heads['ServerHostID']
'ServerHostID'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a dictionary instead of a list, since they are the "replacement" of "associative arrays" in Python.

```
{'ALIAS': 'Alias',
 'CLUSTER': 'Cluster',
 'CPU_ALLOCATED': 'CPU Allocated',
 'DATA_SIZE': 'Data Size',
 'FUNCTIONAL_USE': 'Functional Use',
 'HAS_REMOTE_ACCESS': 'Has Remote Access',
 'HOST_NAME': 'Host Name',
 'HOST_NUMBER': 'Host Number',
 'HOST_OPERATIONAL_STATUS': 'Host Operational Statu',
 'IS_VIRTUAL': 'Is Virtual',
 'LOGICAL_PARTITION': 'Logical Partition',
 'MEMORY_ALLOCATED': 'Memory Allocated',
 'OPERATING_SYSTEM_SOFTWARE': 'Operating System Software',
 'OPERATIONAL_USE': 'Operational Use',
 'PHYSICAL_PARTITION': 'Physical Partition',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'Server Name',
 'SERVER_NUMBER': 'Server Number',
 'SERVER_OPERATIONAL_STATUS': 'Server Operational Status',
 'ServerHostID': 'ServerHostID',
 'UTILIZATION_PERCENTAGE': 'Utilization Percentage',
 'VM_IP_ADDRESS': 'VM IP Address',
 'VM_NAME': 'VM Name'}
```